# Do the Star Wars Marvel Comics have their own universe designation?

Tags: star-wars, marvel

I know there are different universe designations for different storylines, such as the MCU cinematic universe, versus the "main" Marvel Universe or the Ultimates comic universe.

Since Marvel has published Star Wars comics in the past, do these have their own designation/numerical nomenclature?

Something in a dream led to question how the power of the Force would measure against the Infinity Stones and how unlikely it would be for us to ever find out.  Then I remembered, some Marvel Universes have crossed over in the past.  It may be a jumping the shark moment to boost sales, but hey, even DC and Marvel have crossed over in the past, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Despite being (sometimes) published by Marvel, the Star Wars comics are not considered part of the Marvel Multiverse. They are not given a Marvel universe designation in any database I am aware of.

All those published before April 2014 are part of the Star Wars Legends continuity (the Star Wars Expanded Universe at time of publication). All those published later are part of the core Star Wars canon, which comprises a single universe.

Comment: Thank you for answering my rambling answer, I’ve given you the check for your effort in checking databases

Comment: Any time I see the Star Wars Legends continuity mentioned, I always feel bad for the people who spent so many years collecting every book, treasuring the events as canon. Then Disney comes in, "Nope, not canon anymore. Sorry."